# Is the following move constructor code safe?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

This is the move constructor of class `X`:

```
X::X(X&& rhs)
    : base1(std::move(rhs))
    , base2(std::move(rhs))
    , mbr1(std::move(rhs.mbr1))
    , mbr2(std::move(rhs.mbr2))
{ }
```

These are the things I'm wary about:

1. We're moving from `rhs` *twice* and `rhs` isn't guaranteed to be in a valid state. Isn't that undefined behavior for the initialization of `base2`?
2. We're moving the corresponding members of `rhs` to `mbr1` and `mbr2` but since `rhs` was already moved from (and again, it's not guaranteed to be in a valid state) why should this work?

This isn't my code. I found it on a site. Is this move constructor safe? And if so, how?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is approximately how an implicit move constructor typically works: each base and member subobject is move-constructed from the corresponding subobject of `rhs`.

Assuming that `base1` and `base2` are bases of `X` that do not have constructors taking `X` / `X&` / `X&&` / `const X&`, it's safe as written. `std::move(rhs)` will implicitly convert to `base1&&` (respectively `base2&&`) when passed to the base class initializers.

EDIT: The assumption has actually bitten me a couple of times when I had a template constructor in a base class that exactly matched `X&&`. It would be safer (albeit incredibly pedantic) to perform the conversions explicitly:

```
X::X(X&& rhs)
    : base1(std::move(static_cast<base1&>(rhs)))
    , base2(std::move(static_cast<base2&>(rhs)))
    , mbr1(std::move(rhs.mbr1))
    , mbr2(std::move(rhs.mbr2))
{}
```

or even just:

```
X::X(X&& rhs)
    : base1(static_cast<base1&&>(rhs))
    , base2(static_cast<base2&&>(rhs))
    , mbr1(std::move(rhs.mbr1))
    , mbr2(std::move(rhs.mbr2))
{}
```

which I believe should exactly replicate what the compiler would generate implicitly for `X(X&&) = default;` if there are no other base classes or members than `base1`/`base2`/`mbr1`/`mbr2`.

EDIT AGAIN: C++11 §12.8/15 describes the exact structure of the implicit member-wise copy/move constructors.

Comment: Public service announcement:  Casey's answer is equally correct as mine and he beat me by a few minutes. :-)

Answer (score 16):

It depends on the inheritance hierarchy.  But chances are very good that this code is fine.  Here is a complete demo showing that it is safe (for this specific demo):

```
#include <iostream>

struct base1
{
    base1() = default;
    base1(base1&&) {std::cout << "base1(base1&&)\n";}
};

struct base2
{
    base2() = default;
    base2(base2&&) {std::cout << "base2(base2&&)\n";}
};

struct br1
{
    br1() = default;
    br1(br1&&) {std::cout << "br1(br1&&)\n";}
};

struct br2
{
    br2() = default;
    br2(br2&&) {std::cout << "br2(br2&&)\n";}
};

struct X
    : public base1
    , public base2
{
    br1 mbr1;
    br2 mbr2;

public:
    X() = default;
    X(X&& rhs)
    : base1(std::move(rhs))
    , base2(std::move(rhs))
    , mbr1(std::move(rhs.mbr1))
    , mbr2(std::move(rhs.mbr2))
    { }
};

int
main()
{
    X x1;
    X x2 = std::move(x1);
}
```

which should output:

```
base1(base1&&)
base2(base2&&)
br1(br1&&)
br2(br2&&)
```

Here you see that each base and each member is moved exactly once.

---

Remember:  `std::move` doesn't really move.  It is just a cast to rvalue, nothing more.

---

So the code casts to rvalue `X` and then passes that down to the base classes.  Assuming the base classes look like I have outlined above, then there is an implicit cast to rvalue `base1` and `base2`, which will move construct those two separate bases.

Also,

---

Remember:  A moved-from object is in a valid but unspecified state.

---

As long as the move constructor of `base1` and `base2` don't reach up into the derived class and alter `mbr1` or `mbr2`, then those members are still in a known state and ready to be moved from.  No problems.

Now I did mention that problems could occur.  This is how:

```
#include <iostream>

struct base1
{
    base1() = default;
    base1(base1&& b)
         {std::cout << "base1(base1&&)\n";}
    template <class T>
    base1(T&& t)
        {std::cout << "move from X\n";}
};

struct base2
{
    base2() = default;
    base2(base2&& b)
        {std::cout << "base2(base2&&)\n";}
};

struct br1
{
    br1() = default;
    br1(br1&&) {std::cout << "br1(br1&&)\n";}
};

struct br2
{
    br2() = default;
    br2(br2&&) {std::cout << "br2(br2&&)\n";}
};

struct X
    : public base1
    , public base2
{
    br1 mbr1;
    br2 mbr2;

public:
    X() = default;
    X(X&& rhs)
    : base1(std::move(rhs))
    , base2(std::move(rhs))
    , mbr1(std::move(rhs.mbr1))
    , mbr2(std::move(rhs.mbr2))
    { }
};

int
main()
{
    X x1;
    X x2 = std::move(x1);
}
```

In this example, `base1` has a templated constructor that takes an rvalue-something.  If this constructor can bind to an rvalue `X`, and if this constructor will move from the rvalue `X`, **then** you have problems:

```
move from X
base2(base2&&)
br1(br1&&)
br2(br2&&)
```

The way to fix this problem (which is relatively rare, but not vanishingly rare), is to `forward<base1>(rhs)` instead of `move(rhs)`:

```
    X(X&& rhs)
    : base1(std::forward<base1>(rhs))
    , base2(std::move(rhs))
    , mbr1(std::move(rhs.mbr1))
    , mbr2(std::move(rhs.mbr2))
    { }
```

Now `base1` sees an rvalue `base1` instead of an rvalue `X`, and that will bind to the `base1` move constructor (assuming it exists), and so you again get:

```
base1(base1&&)
base2(base2&&)
br1(br1&&)
br2(br2&&)
```

And all again is good with the world.

Comment: Demos prove it works, demos do not prove it's safe.  (presumably his code already worked, he's asking if it was safe)

Comment: `std::forward<base1>(rhs)` that's... wierd.  I think that works but I wouldn't consider that "good" code (I can't believe I'm saying that to Howard Hinnant), though it's possible you could change my mind.  Why not just use a `static_cast<base1&&>`? (

Comment: Nice use of `forward<base>` - you committee members know all the best tricks!

Comment: Yeah I would've probably used `static_cast` instead of `forward`, nice.

Comment: @MooingDuck:  In this example, `static_cast<base1&&>(rhs)` works just as well.  Circumstances can arise where the use of `forward<T>` is safer than the use of `static_cast<T&&>`.  Examples have been documented in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2951.html , use cases C and F.  In these (admittedly rarer) use cases, the use of `forward` will fail with a compile time error, whereas the use of `static_cast` will fail with a run time error.

Comment: On second thought, I would go back to my first instinct and stick with `std::move(static_cast<base1&>(rhs))` which is incredibly wordy, but spells out intent very clearly in small words that everyone would get immediately. The reactions in these comments demonstrate that use of `forward` here is a bit "clever."

Comment: What about `std::move<base1>(rhs)`? That should be equivalent.

Comment: @0x499602D2: It may have to be `std::move<base1&&>(rhs)` I think

Comment: @0x499602D2:  It is equivalent.  I don't recommend it.  `std::move` is typically used with deduced templated arguments.  `std::forward` can never be used with deduced template arguments.  Read `std::move(x)` as: cast x to rvalue.  Read `std::forward<T>(u)` as: cast `u` to `T&&`, recalling that if `T` is an lvalue reference, reference collapsing will occur.  Specifically, `std::forward<base1>(rhs)` says: forward `rhs` as an rvalue `base1`.  And `static_cast<base1&&>(rhs)` also says that exact same thing.

Comment: I still don't understand why the language feature "cast x to rvalue" was named `std::move`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  It was first proposed here http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1377.htm#Returning%20A&& in 2002.  It did not become controversial until about a decade later.

Comment: Further comment on `forward<T>(u)` vs `static_cast<T&&>(u)`:  Sometimes people can become confused as to whether the "`&&`" is necessary or not.  It is definitely necessary with `static_cast`, as `static_cast<T>(u)` induces a copy, not just a cast.  Whereas `forward<T>(u)` and `forward<T&&>(u)` are exactly equivalent.  So if you are prone to not knowing, or accidentally dropping the &&, `forward` will save you, but `static_cast` may silently cost you a copy.

Comment: @Howard: The notion that Earth is at the centre of the universe was not controversial for hundreds (if not thousands) of years after it was first proposed; does not make it any less ridiculous ;) I note that the paper you cite does not present a rationale for the name `std::move`, let alone one with which I will inevitably disagree.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  I was trying to be polite.  Now I will put it more bluntly:  everyone, including yourself, had plenty of time to object, and failed to do so in a timely manner.  Maybe 2002 was before your time, I don't know.  But the design went through an extraordinarily long design review time.  The naming of `move` was never picked up as controversial until it was too late to do anything about.  This isn't about basic physics being wrong.  This is simply a design detail that no one considered important enough, or objectionable enough to complain about for a decade.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: And technically, the paper does include the rationale:  "Thus swap can be made more readable."  You may not agree with the rationale, and I respect that.  But there it is.  Readability in algorithms such as swap.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: The way I read it, that's presented as a rationale to come up with a short alternative to the `static_cast<T&&>`, not as a rationale to call that alternative `std::move` (as opposed to something else) when no move is in fact performed by this feature. Yes, 2002 was before I'd so much as read the standard. I didn't mean to cause you any offence and I don't see a need to get defensive and somehow blame me for not speaking up sooner: I simply don't like the name `std::move` for this. That's just my opinion, and I'm just stating it. That's _it_! :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  Fair enough.  For a while there I thought you might be confusing syntax sugar for mankind's long, never ending quest to understand his physical world.  Please feel free to use `static_cast` in your code, or to write your own `std::move` replacement.  There is absolutely no magic under the covers here, and you should be able to easily get the syntax to your liking.  This is a library feature, not a language feature (and thus easy to replace).  Might I suggest: `set_value_category_to_xvalue(T&&)`?  This is very clear and precise on what the functionality actually does.

Answer (score 2):

No, that would be an example of **possible** undefined behavior. It might work a lot of the time, but it's not guaranteed to. C++ allows it, but you are the one who has to make sure you don't try to use `rhs` again in that way. You are trying to use `rhs` three times after <strike>its guts had been ripped out</strike> **its `rvalue` reference was passed to a function that might potentially move from it (leaving it in an undefined state).**

Comment: @MooingDuck Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I knew that at some point but I forgot. Is my answer more correct now?

Comment: Oh wait, I hadn't considered that `base1` or `base2` might be constructable from a `X&&`.  In that case your answer is right, that it might possibly be undefined depending on the constructors of `base1` and `base2`.  I just hadn't made the connection that the `base1` constructor might _not_ implicitly convert `X&&` to a `base1&&`.  Sorry for the unnecessary confusion.