# Derived class of Move constructor confusion

Tags: c++, c++11

I know move semantics in c++ move constructor, but here I have some confusion:

```
class Derived: public Base {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    std::string name;
    // ...
public:
    // ...
    // move semantics
    Derived(Derived&& x)              // rvalues bind here
        : Base(std::move(x)), 
        vec(std::move(x.vec)),
        name(std::move(x.name)) { }

    Derived& operator=(Derived&& x)   // rvalues bind here
    {
        Base::operator=(std::move(x));
        vec  = std::move(x.vec);
        name = std::move(x.name);
        return *this;
    }
    // ...
};
```

the move constructor Base(std::move(x)),  the x have been converted to rvalue reference, how does vec(std::move(x.vec)) ?? 
still x existing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the following code safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345515/is-the-following-code-safe)

Answer (score 5):

The move constructor for `Base` presumably has the prototype `Base(Base&& b)`, so when you call `Base(std::move(x))` in the constructor, the rvalue `std::move(x)`, which has type `Derived`, is implicitly converted to an rvalue of type `Base`. The move constructor for `Base` sees an rvalue reference to `Base`, so it moves the members of `Base` out of `x`. The other members of `x` have not been moved from yet, so the following move-initializations are still valid.

Move construction and move assignment don't invalidate an object. An object's invariants should still be satisfied after a move, so that its destructor will work properly.

Comment: you mean, Base(Base&& b) just move the base part? Move construction and move assignment don't invalidate an object. An object's invariants should still be satisfied after a move, so that its destructor will work properly.  Is this still valid besides move construction and move assignment?

Comment: I'm a bit confused here too, `x` is of type `Derived`, so wouldn't `std::move(x)` call `std::move(Derived&& x)` leading to a loop?

Comment: @bryantism, yes, the base move constructor only moves the base class's members.

Comment: @user1520427, nope, why would you think that?

Comment: @BrianBi because it's of type `Derived`, so surely it'd resolve to a function accepting something of type `Derived`. However, this answer in the question linked to by 0x499602D2 cleans it up: "Remember: std::move doesn't really move. It is just a cast to rvalue, nothing more."

Comment: @BrianBi So to clarify, it was me misunderstanding :)

Comment: @BrianBi if Base constructor does have a Base(Base&& rhs) and so on, maybe it's not safe?  It depends on the implementation?

Comment: @bryantism, indeed; and if not, this code just won't compile at all. Note that even if you don't define a move constructor for `Base` explicitly, one might be implicitly defaulted by the compiler (provided you haven't defined a copy constructor, copy assignment operator, move assignment operator, or destructor)