# Is it OK to move from r-value reference to sub-object of temporary?

Tags: c++, move, base-class

If a temporary `Derived` is passed to a method that takes a `Base&&`, is it OK to move-construct Base from that?

Comment: It depends on what effect of move-construction has on your `Base` type. If it leaves the `Derived` object in a valid state, then yes. Otherwise, no.

Comment: It seems dubious to me, to empty a sub-object. Does the enclosing object destruction (at the end of the expression evaluation) go OK, with an emptied sub-object?

Comment: If the move-constructing code you wrote for your types leaves it in a valid state, then yes. Otherwise, no.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: "valid state" is so ill-defined.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I mean what that word would mean in any discussion of move semantics; able to be destroyed (and reassigned, if the type is assignable).

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Unfortunately, there's some disagreement over exactly what it means (and further, about what it should mean). Just for example, if the source contains pointers, should they be set to nullptr when moved from? Common practice says yes, but some (e.g., Sean Parent) advocate against doing so.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: How can one say whether some pointer should be set to 0 without knowing what that pointer represents? Mike clearly named all requirements for an object after being moved from: Safely assignable (to and from, move or not) as well as safey destructible.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345515/is-the-following-move-constructor-code-safe

Comment: @Deduplicator: I suppose in the absolutely general sense, you can't. But in the common case, transferring ownership of the pointee from source to destination, it's common to zero-out the pointer in the source so it's apparent that it no longer owns (or has access) to that resource.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Which is why I didn't try to define exactly what the word might mean in the context of these particular classes that we know nothing about. Any particular type will have its definition of "valid", and move-construction is OK if it leaves the object in such a state, and not otherwise. Sorry if my throwaway comment was too terse for the language lawyers.

Comment: If it's an owning pointer and an object with that pointer zeroed conforms to the requirements, yes, that's the best thing to do.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Not at all--I don't object to keeping the explanation minimal, but do think it's worth at least pointing out that (for example) if the OP tries to find a definition of what's needed, he should expect to see some disagreement over what he really needs to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The temporaries lifetime is extended until the end of the function (or the lifetime of the parameter, respectively), so you can move construct a `Base` object from that reference.

Note that you need an additional `std::move` to make it a move and not a copy:

```
Base b = std::move(param);
```

The temporary object you move from is left in whatever state is specified for moved-from object of its type. Standard library types  like `vector<int>` or `string` have a so-called "valid but unspecified state" -- basically the only sensible operations you can do are assign (that is, copy or move into it) or destroy it. Without information about `Base`' move constructor definition no further assumptions can be made.

Comment: OK, but I'm worried not about lifetime but about the state in which the full object is left.

Comment: @haelix Extended the answer. I am still not quite sure what you are essentially asking -- what shall be "ok"?

Comment: @Deduplicator You mean the valid but unspecified state can be assigned to another object?

Comment: Sure. Which would make that other object "valid but unspecified" too. (BTW: It's not so much that objects have a unique "valid but unspecified" state, but that we don't know (and should not care) which valid state they have.)

Comment: @Deduplicator I know all that. I just don't understand why you mentioned it. In the post I enumerated the *sensible* operations you can do with moved-from objects. Assigning them to some other object is pointless, isn't it?

Comment: @Loopunroller: Quite. At least I don't know any reason to do so. It might conceivably somehow come up in heavily templated code, but that's still unlikely. Also, maybe you should make a mention of "proper encapsulation" as a pre-condition in your answer...

Comment: +1 and accepted, because I think I got the point. Thanks also to all who commented. I believe that the sub-object being in 'valid but unspecified state' also makes the full object be in 'valid but unspecified state'.